# Find the number of possible combinations in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinations

This is the problems I am trying to solve:

Given an undirected graph, find the number of different unordered combinations of nodes that can be obtained by traversing a path between any two nodes and keeping track of what nodes that we went to (without going to any node twice).

Say for example that the adjacency matrix is:

```
1: 2,3
2: 1,3,4
3: 1,2,4
4: 2,3,5
5: 4
```

One unordered combination would be [1,2,3,4] which could be obtained by going in the path 1>3>4>2 or 1>3>2>4

The answer would be 17 with the following unordered sets:

```
[1,2] [1,3] [2,3] [2,4] [3,4] [4,5] 
[1,2,3] [1,2,4] [1,3,4] [2,3,4] [2,4,5] [3,4,5] 
[1,2,3,4] [1,2,4,5] [1,3,4,5] [2,3,4,5] 
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Currently, what my function does in my program is just brute force all of the possibilities, but I was wondering if there was any faster ways to do it if the graph had 10,000+ nodes? Brute forcing would be way too slow.

Comment: There's not much hope for an efficient solution to this problem. At some point the algorithm needs to decide whether there's a path that connects every node (without visiting any node twice). That's known as the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is NP-Complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user this algorithm :

sort the nodes by `name` for example `N_0,...,N_k`

```
define an `result` set which is empty at beginning
for `i` from `0` to `k` do the following
 set node `n_i` as root
 step 1: list of all 'n_i` neighbors like `n_j` which `j>i`
 add all of these pairs to `result` set
 set `n_j` as root
 go to step 1
end
```